# Replacing Div content with another using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a div named `Groupz` and another div named `vegasDetailz`

Now i want, when i click on the button that is lying in first div , first div should disappear and the second div should take it's place for this purpose i have written the following jquery code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("#vegasDetailz").replaceWith("#Groupz");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="vegasDetailz">
  <input class="submitBTN getstart" name="button" type="submit" value="Get Started">
</div>
<div id="Groupz"></div>
```

But it is not working for me. Any ideas ?

**Note: I am using php laravel 5.3**

Comment: Your button selector is wrong, `$("input[name="button"]").click(function(){`

Comment: hide and show the div

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to click on `$("button")` but you have no `button`, so use `$(".getstart")`, since it is the id of your input.

Second your `.replaceWith("#Groupz")` are just trying text into the div, you have to get the element first before you can replace the entire element. Like `.replaceWith($("#Groupz"))`

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div  id="vegasDetailz">

 <input class="submitBTN getstart" name="button" type="submit" value="Get Started">
 </div>

  <div id="Groupz">
  </div>
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $(".getstart").click(function(){
        $("#vegasDetailz").replaceWith($("#Groupz").html("Im an replaced"));
    });
  });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the name as you selector then use like this `input[name=button]` if you want to use class as your selector then use `.submitBTN`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#Groupz").hide();
  $(".submitBTN").click(function() { // you can also use input[name=button] for '.submitBTN'
    $("#vegasDetailz").hide();
    $("#Groupz").show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="vegasDetailz">

  <input class="submitBTN getstart" name="button" type="submit" value="Get Started">
</div>
<div id="Groupz">
  Hai Another div
</div>
```

Comment: the param of replaceWith should html ?

Comment: May i know the requirement  @Learner

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to show & hide the `div` on the button click, then try this code:

```
<div  id="vegasDetailz">
     <input class="submitBTN getstart" name="button" type="submit" value="Get Started">
 </div>
 <div id="Groupz" style="display:none;">Hello</div>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $(".getstart").click(function(){
        $("#vegasDetailz").css('display','none');
        $("#Groupz").css('display','block');
    });
  });
 </script>
```

Just make the `div` id named `Groupz` hidden by default, if you don't want to show the second div in default state.

I hope, it may be helpful to you.

Comment: He clearly ask for a way to replace the div with another

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `submitBTN getstart` from the div `vegasDetailz` then add new one to the second div `Groupz`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
     $(".getstart").click(function(){
            $(".getstart").remove();
            $("#Groupz").append($("<input class='getstart' name='button' type='submit' value='Get Started'>"));
        });
      });
```

```css
#vegasDetailz {
  background-color: grey;
  width:500px;
  height:60px;
}
#Groupz {
  width:500px;
  background-color:pink;
  height:60px;
  margin-top:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div  id="vegasDetailz">
  <input class="getstart" name="button" type="submit" value="Get Started">
</div>
    
<div id="Groupz">
</div>
```